# ItemTouchHelper - Can't scroll RecyclerView, Swipe doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

Well, at the beginning of the Implementation of `ItemTouchHelper`, I chose to use only the Swipe function from it. Everything worked - with the help of Swipe I could delete items in `RecyclerView` etc. But then I thought I'd add up-down movement so that the user could change the order in which the item appears in the list.
Then the problems began - the user can change the order in which items are displayed, but can no longer:

- Scroll `RecyclerView` (even if **changing item up-down position is disabled**)
- Swipe functions have stopped working - `onSwiped` does not return the side (`ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT`) in which the item was swiped

I changed the View on which is trigger OnStartDragListener from _view to just ImageView and I can scroll now but there are now other problems:

- Swipe works on that ImageView too - I want to be able to swipe item whereever user click on item (_view)
- Swipe functions still doesn't work - `onSwiped` does not return the side (`ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT`) in which the item was swiped

[Video how the problem looks](https://streamable.com/mynx39)

**FIXED**

*I Changed*

```java
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags =
                mDraggable
                        ? ItemTouchHelper.UP
                                | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
                                | ItemTouchHelper.START
                                | ItemTouchHelper.END
                        : 0;
        if (mDraggable) {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        } else {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        }
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
    }
```

*To*

```java
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = 0;
        int swipeFlags = 0;
        if (mDraggable) {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
        } else {
            swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
            return makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
        }
    }
```

**RecyclerView Adapter**:

```
package tw.codeassist.plus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import tw.codeassist.plus.SwipeToDeleteCallback;

public class CodeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CodeAdapter.ViewHolder> implements SwipeToDeleteCallback.ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _data;
    Context context;
    SharedPreferences snippets;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    //private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final tw.codeassist.plus.SwipeToDeleteCallback.OnStartDragListener mDragStartListener;
    
    public CodeAdapter(
            android.content.Context appCont,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> _arr,
            tw.codeassist.plus.SwipeToDeleteCallback.OnStartDragListener dragListner) {
        _data = _arr;
        context = appCont;
        mDragStartListener = dragListner;
        
        snippets = context.getSharedPreferences("snippets", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater _inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View _v = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.codesnippets, null);
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams _lp =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        _v.setLayoutParams(_lp);
        return new ViewHolder(_v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder _holder, final int _position) {
        View _view = _holder.itemView;

        final androidx.cardview.widget.CardView cardview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.cardview1);
        final LinearLayout main_linear = (LinearLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.main_linear);
        final LinearLayout color_linear = (LinearLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.color_linear);
        final LinearLayout linear3 = (LinearLayout) _view.findViewById(R.id.linear3);
        final TextView title_txt = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.title_txt);
        final TextView desc_txt = (TextView) _view.findViewById(R.id.desc_txt);

        title_txt.setTypeface(
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/product_sans_bold.ttf"), 0);
        desc_txt.setTypeface(
                Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/product_sans_regular.ttf"), 0);
        title_txt.setText(_data.get((int) _position).get("Title").toString());
        desc_txt.setText(_data.get((int) _position).get("Description").toString());
        color_linear.setBackgroundColor(
                Color.parseColor(_data.get((int) _position).get("Color").toString()));
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams _lp =
                new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        _view.setLayoutParams(_lp);

        _view.setOnTouchListener(
                new View.OnTouchListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            mDragStartListener.onStartDrag(_holder);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return _data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mItemClickListener != null) {
                mItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClear() {
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        _data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        Log.d("onItemMove", "Log position" + fromPosition + " " + toPosition);
        if (fromPosition < _data.size() && toPosition < _data.size()) {
            if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i < toPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(_data, i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = fromPosition; i > toPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(_data, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
            Collections.reverse(_data);
            snippets.edit().putString("CodeSnippets", new Gson().toJson(this._data)).commit();
            notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText((Activity) context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        _data = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {
        _data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, _data.size());
    }
    
    public interface ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

        void onItemSelected();

        void onItemClear();
    }
}
```

**ItemTouchHelper Callback**

```
package tw.codeassist.plus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

    private CodeAdapter mAdapter;
    Context context;
    private SharedPreferences snippets;

    private Drawable icon;
    private Drawable icon2;
    private GradientDrawable background; // ColorDrawable Before

    boolean mDraggable = true;

    public SwipeToDeleteCallback(Context con, CodeAdapter adapter, boolean canEdit) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
        context = con;
        setDraggable(canEdit);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) con).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        float densityScale = dm.density;

        // DELETE ICON
        Drawable dr = con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
        icon =
                new BitmapDrawable(
                        con.getResources(),
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                bitmap,
                                (int) (150 * densityScale / 3),
                                (int) (150 * densityScale / 3),
                                true));

        // COPY ICON
        Drawable dr2 = con.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_copy);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) dr2).getBitmap();
        icon2 =
                new BitmapDrawable(
                        con.getResources(),
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                                bitmap2,
                                (int) (200 * densityScale / 3),
                                (int) (200 * densityScale / 3),
                                true));

        // TO INIT THE background
        int startColor = Color.WHITE;
        int endColor = Color.RED;
        background =
                new GradientDrawable(
                        GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {startColor, endColor});
        background.setCornerRadius(20);
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags =
                mDraggable
                        ? ItemTouchHelper.UP
                                | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
                                | ItemTouchHelper.START
                                | ItemTouchHelper.END
                        : 0;
        if (mDraggable) {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        } else {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        }
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
    }

    public void setDraggable(boolean value) {
        mDraggable = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(
            RecyclerView recyclerView,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (mDraggable) {
            mAdapter.onItemMove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    void showMessage(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(((Activity) context), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
        showMessage(String.valueOf(direction));
        
        if (direction == 8) { // RIGHT TO LEFT
            // copy
            VibrateNotify(200);
            String getCode = mAdapter._data.get((int) position).get("Code").toString();
            CharSequence code = getCode;

            LinearLayout linearSnack =
                    (LinearLayout) ((FragmentActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.linear1);

            ((ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE))
                    .setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", code));
            com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.make(
                            context,
                            linearSnack,
                            "Code Copied!",
                            com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction(
                            "",
                            new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View _view) {}
                            })
                    .show();
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        } else if (direction == 4) { // 4 = LEFT TO RIGHT
            // delete
            mAdapter.removeAt(position);
            VibrateNotify(500);
            snippets = context.getSharedPreferences("snippets", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            snippets.edit().putString("CodeSnippets", new Gson().toJson(mAdapter._data)).commit();
            mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public void VibrateNotify(long duration) {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(duration, VibrationEffect.EFFECT_DOUBLE_CLICK));
        } else {
            // deprecated in API 26
            v.vibrate(duration);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(
            Canvas c,
            RecyclerView recyclerView,
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
            float dX,
            float dY,
            int actionState,
            boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        int backgroundCornerOffset = 15; // so background is behind the rounded corners of itemView
        int alpha = 128;
        int colorGreen = Color.parseColor("#FF0000FF");
        icon.setAlpha(alpha);
        icon2.setAlpha(alpha);
        int iconMargin = (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 3;
        int iconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemView.getHeight() - icon.getIntrinsicHeight()) / 2;
        int iconBottom = iconTop + icon.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (dX > 0) { // Swiping to the right
            int iconLeft = itemView.getLeft() + iconMargin; // icon.getIntrinsicWidth()
            int iconRight = iconLeft + icon.getIntrinsicWidth(); // itemView.getLeft()
            icon2.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);
            int START = 0xFF90A4AE;
            int END = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            background =
                    new GradientDrawable(
                            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {START, END});
            background.setCornerRadius(20);
            background.setBounds(
                    itemView.getLeft(),
                    itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getLeft() + ((int) dX) + backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getBottom());
        } else if (dX < 0) { // Swiping to the left
            int iconLeft = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin - icon.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int iconRight = itemView.getRight() - iconMargin;
            icon.setBounds(iconLeft, iconTop, iconRight, iconBottom);
            int START = Color.TRANSPARENT;
            int END = 0xFFE57373;
            background =
                    new GradientDrawable(
                            GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT, new int[] {START, END});
            background.setCornerRadius(20);
            background.setBounds(
                    itemView.getRight() + ((int) dX) - backgroundCornerOffset,
                    itemView.getTop(),
                    itemView.getRight(),
                    itemView.getBottom());
        } else { // view is unSwiped
            icon.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            icon2.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
            background.setBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        background.setStroke(25, Color.TRANSPARENT);
        // background.setPadding(0, paddingTop, 0, paddingBottom); //left, top, right, bottom
        background.draw(c);
        icon.draw(c);
        icon2.draw(c);
    }

    public interface OnStartDragListener {

        void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
    }

    public interface ItemTouchHelperAdapter {

        boolean onItemMove(int fromPosition, int toPosition);

        void onItemDismiss(int position);
    }
}
```

**Fragment where the RecyclerView is**:

```
package tw.codeassist.plus;


import android.animation.*;
import android.app.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.*;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.*;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.*;
import android.media.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.text.*;
import android.text.style.*;
import android.util.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.view.animation.*;
import android.webkit.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.*;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.*;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.github.angads25.filepicker.*;
import com.github.dhaval2404.colorpicker.*;
import com.google.android.flexbox.*;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.zip4j.*;
import io.github.rosemoe.sora.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex.*;
import org.json.*;

public class TutorialsFragmentActivity extends Fragment
        implements SwipeToDeleteCallback.OnStartDragListener {

    private FloatingActionButton _fab;
    private CodeAdapter codeAdapter;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> dataToShow = new ArrayList<>();

    public LinearLayout linear1;
    private TextView textview1;
    private TextView goneTxt;
    private TextView editBttn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayout noCodesView;

   TutorialsFragmentActivity tfa = this;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;

    private Intent intent = new Intent();
    private SharedPreferences snippets;
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    private ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper;

    boolean isEditMode = false;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater _inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup _container,
            @Nullable Bundle _savedInstanceState) {
        View _view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorials_fragment, _container, false);
        initialize(_savedInstanceState, _view);
        com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getContext());
        initializeLogic();
        return _view;
    }

    private void initialize(Bundle _savedInstanceState, View _view) {
        _fab = _view.findViewById(R.id._fab);
        
        settings = getContext().getSharedPreferences("settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        noCodesView = _view.findViewById(R.id.linearNoCodes);
        linear1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.linear1);
        goneTxt = _view.findViewById(R.id.txGone);
        editBttn = _view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
        textview1 = _view.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        recyclerView = _view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        snippets = getContext().getSharedPreferences("snippets", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

        listener =
                new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
                    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                        if (key.equals("CodeSnippets")) {
                            if (settings.getString("ShouldRefresh", "") == "true") {
                                itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
                            dataToShow =
                                    new Gson()
                                            .fromJson(
                                                    snippets.getString("CodeSnippets", ""),
                                                    new TypeToken<
                                                            ArrayList<
                                                                    HashMap<
                                                                            String,
                                                                            Object>>>() {}.getType());
                            Collections.reverse(dataToShow);
                            codeAdapter = new CodeAdapter(getContext(), dataToShow, tfa);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(codeAdapter);
                            //recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
                            itemTouchHelper =
                                    new ItemTouchHelper(
                                            new SwipeToDeleteCallback(
                                                    getContext(), codeAdapter, false));
                            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
                            settings.edit().putString("ShouldRefresh", "false").commit();
                            } else {
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

        snippets.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

        goneTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        editBttn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                        if (!isEditMode) {
                            isEditMode = true;
                            editBttn.setText("Close");
                            goneTxt.setText("Close");
                        } else {
                            isEditMode = false;
                            editBttn.setText("Edit");
                            goneTxt.setText("Edit");
                        }

                        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
                        itemTouchHelper =
                                new ItemTouchHelper(
                                        new SwipeToDeleteCallback(
                                                getContext(), codeAdapter, isEditMode));
                        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
                    }
                });

        _fab.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View _view) {
                        editBttn.setText("Edit");
                        goneTxt.setText("Edit");
                        isEditMode = false;
                        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(null);
                        itemTouchHelper =
                                new ItemTouchHelper(
                                        new SwipeToDeleteCallback(
                                                getContext(), codeAdapter, isEditMode));
                        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

                        intent.setClass(
                                getContext().getApplicationContext(), AddSnippetActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void initializeLogic() {
        {
            android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable SketchUi =
                    new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable();
            int clrs[] = {0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFE0E0E0};
            SketchUi =
                    new android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable(
                            android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM,
                            clrs);
            linear1.setBackground(SketchUi);
        }
        noCodesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textview1.setTypeface(
                Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/product_sans_bold.ttf"),
                0);
        dataToShow =
                new Gson()
                        .fromJson(
                                snippets.getString("CodeSnippets", ""),
                                new TypeToken<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>>() {}.getType());
        Collections.reverse(dataToShow);
        codeAdapter = new CodeAdapter(this.getContext(), dataToShow, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(codeAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        itemTouchHelper =
                new ItemTouchHelper(new SwipeToDeleteCallback(getContext(), codeAdapter, false));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

        removeScrollBar(recyclerView);

        if (dataToShow.size() == 0) {
            noCodesView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            noCodesView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void removeScrollBar(View _view) {
        _view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        _view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartDrag(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        itemTouchHelper.startDrag(viewHolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually for drag & drop(changing item order). I handle it using providing the dedicated drag icon in item instead of putting on complete item. You can find example here: https://howtodoandroid.com/drag-and-drop-recyclerview-item/

Comment: This fixed the problem with scroll RecyclerView, but instead there is another problem because Swipe also works only on this button, which is also responsible for moving item up-down and 'onSwiped' still does not return which way was Swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FIXED**

*I Changed*

```java
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags =
                mDraggable
                        ? ItemTouchHelper.UP
                                | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
                                | ItemTouchHelper.START
                                | ItemTouchHelper.END
                        : 0;
        if (mDraggable) {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
        } else {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT;
        }
        return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
    }
```

*To*

```java
    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        int dragFlags = 0;
        int swipeFlags = 0;
        if (mDraggable) {
            dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;
            return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0);
        } else {
            swipeFlags = ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END;
            return makeMovementFlags(0, swipeFlags);
        }
    }
```